# How do I stop the iPhone from adding text attachments when I send pictures?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, mobile-mail, attachments

Every time I select two photos from the gallery and mail them, the iPhone also adds two text attachments. How do I get it to stop that?

Answer (score 2):

This is the fault of Microsoft Exchange and not specific to iOS.

> This happens because Microsoft Exchange Server is reformatting messages sent through it.
>
> The Exchange server insists that message text must always be first and attachments must always be last. As soon as the Exchange software sees one attachment in a message, it stops looking for text, and treats anything else in that message as an attachment. Any remaining text sections are converted into attachment sections, and given fake file names (like "ATT00001.htm").
>
> At this time, there is no way to make the Exchange server stop turning text sections into attachment sections. The only workaround is to include attachments at the end of a message, after text and after any signatures.

<sup>http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4981187</sup>

> The body of a message is shown incorrectly as an attachment if you try to use an application in an Exchange Server environment to send a message that includes attachments

> Applies to Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 Enterprise, Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 Standard, Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 Enterprise Edition, Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 Standard Edition

<sup>http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969854</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug at Microsoft's end for Outlook accounts which use stock Mail app for iOS. There is absolutely no way in iOS to resolve this issue.

I avoid the **ATT00001.txt** file attachment by simply signing into my Outlook mail via the **Other** option. The steps to setup differ slightly across recent iOS releases. They are mentioned separately for recent iOS releases:

- Under iOS 9, go to `Settings app -> Mail, Contact, Calendars -> Add Account -> Other` and enter appropriate information.
- Under iOS 10 go to `Settings app -> Mail -> Add Account -> Other` and enter appropriate information.
- Under iOS 11, go to `Settings app -> Accounts & Passwords -> Add Account -> Other` and enter appropriate information.